# How to show video with media player in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, media-player

How can I add media player in codeigniter,

I use below code, but still can't show the video :

```
<video width="205" height="180" controls>
  <source src="application/views/web/videostreaming/video2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="application/views/web/videostreaming/video2.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
  <source src="application/views/web/videostreaming/video2.flv" type="video/flv" />
</video>
```

I added video sources in application/config/mimes.php like this:

```
            'mp4'   =>  'video/mp4',
            'flv'   =>  'video/flv',
            'ogv'   =>  'video/ogv',
```

output error is:

> No video with supported format and MIME type found

please help me to resolve this problem, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error `No video with supported format and MIME type found` is a client-side issue, meaning that the browser cannot play any of your provided video files. Changing the CodeIgniter mime types isn't going to help you (unless perhaps you are processing all requests including those for static files through PHP). Check that your MP4 file is using H.264/AAC codices, and you OGV file is the Theora/Vorbis codicies and that these file paths are correct (you may want to dynamically create absolute paths using CodeIgniter's `base_url()` function).

Answer (score 0):

The video tag is something new in html5 and doesn't support by browsers well.
i recommend you :

1. Flash (.swf) media player for html
2. [Embed  Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_videoembed)

Comment: how i can use that ? can you give me example ?

Comment: i using like this to call file 
video src = "../application/views/web/videostreaming/video.flv"

Comment: <embed src="intro.swf" width="200" height="200">